# How to achieve horizontal scrolling for multiple rows in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

In flutter need to arrange n number of elements in two rows and scroll this rows together.

Able to achieve vertical scrolling by Wrap, but not able to achieve horizontal scrolling, please help....

Comment: can you try this: 'have you tried giving the same controller to them and them moving one with other on the state change of the other one.'

Answer (score 3):

```
SingleChildScrollView(
 child: 
   Column( children:[
Row(children:[])
Row(children:[])
]))
```

And set the scroll direction of the the `SingleChildScrollView` to horizontal. No need for any controllers.

Comment: scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal needed